# CakePHP: Filter view on multiple criteria only returns one result

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to build a rudimentary search feature into my CakePHP application. There are only two fields that need to be searchable. I have code in my controller to take the two search values from a form:

```
$options = array('Model.id' => $this->request->data['Model']['id'],
    'Model.field2' => $this->request->data['Model']['field2']);

$this->set('views', $this->Paginator->paginate('Model', $options));
```

Both of these inputs come from dropdown lists and both are required. Right now, when I run my search, it only returns one result, the first selectable option in the field2 dropdown, like so:

```
ID   Field2
1    Value1

OR

ID   Field2
2    Value1
```

If I search for any other value in field2, I get no result. If I comment out the dropdown for field2 and just search for ID, I get all the rows with that ID (around 500, which is expected). Why is my result set empty when I search on an ID and any value other than Value1 in my second dropdown?

Comment: you are passing a `WHERE AND` query, `where model.id=request[model][id] and model.field2 = request[model][field2]` is this what you want?

Comment: Correct. The ID is attached to 500 records, but each record belongsTo one corresponding field2 value. Both are keyed off of a sequence number (1-500) that exists in both tables.

Comment: I believe your `$options` array needs to be an element inside an outer array with the `conditions` key. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$options` array passed as an argument to `paginate` can contain multiple keys, similar to the ones used by `Model->find()`

First build the `$conditions` array

```
$conditions = array('Model.id' => $this->request->data['Model']['id'],
    'Model.field2' => $this->request->data['Model']['field2']);
```

Then the `$options`

```
$options['conditions'] = $conditions
```

Then pass it to `paginate`

```
$this->set('views', $this->Paginator->paginate('Model', $options));
```

---

Update:

```
$conditions = array('Model.id' => $this->request->data['Model']['id'],
        'Model.field2' => $this->request->data['Model']['field2']);
$options['conditions'] = $conditions;

$this->Paginator->settings = $options;
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Model');

$this->set('views', $data);
```

Comment: Hmm. When I try that, I get the following SQL error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conditions' in 'where clause'".

Comment: correct, I confused things a bit, try the updated code. Although from what I see in the docs your approach should also work.

Comment: Thanks. No longer getting the SQL error, but I'm back to only having the first row of my query returned. If you need to look at my Model or View code, let me know and I'll update the original post.

Comment: So, after days of me and my coworker tearing our hair out, it turns out that the problem was never with the code, but with the DATA. Every table row after the first one had a carriage return in it, which was throwing off the result set. The CR was being read as a string, but it wasn't visible in MySQL or in phpMyAdmin. Corrected the import function that was causing this and now my result sets are returning what they're supposed to. Marked your answer as correct.